# Invalid syntax inside dateutil when importing tensorflow. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-dateutil

Here is the transcript:

```
dims@calculon:~$ pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (170.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 170.1MB 10kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Downloading tensorflow_tensorboard-0.4.0rc2-py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.7MB 844kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting enum34>=1.1.6 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Downloading enum34-1.1.6-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.3.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow-gpu)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-tensorboard, enum34, tensorflow-gpu
  Found existing installation: tensorflow-tensorboard 0.1.8
    Uninstalling tensorflow-tensorboard-0.1.8:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-tensorboard-0.1.8
Successfully installed enum34-1.1.6 tensorflow-gpu-1.4.0 tensorflow-tensorboard-0.4.0rc2
dims@calculon:~$ python
Python 3.5.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov  4 2017, 10:11:29)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator_lib as estimator
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs import inputs
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/inputs.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.numpy_io import numpy_input_fn
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.queues import feeding_functions
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_functions.py", line 40, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 361, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What backqoutes mean in python at all?

Comment: That's Python 2 syntax. You appear to have installed a Python 2 package on Python 3.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall dateutil and see if that helps.

Comment: That would probably a *very* old version of `python-dateutil`. It may be some system-installed version on a distro that still distributes the last python 2 only version.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation

```
pip install python-dateutil --upgrade
```

helped.

This was the result of playing python versions in Anaconda. Althoug I never tried <3.4